# Logging into Website Using Java

Tags: java, html, web

First of all yes I know there are a million questions that ask the same thing but none of their answers are working. I am using the following code:

```
    URL objtest = new URL("http://rccpdems01/ems/Login.php");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) objtest.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
    String datas = "userid=G434326&psword=TestPass";
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(datas);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

However the lines that are being returned makes it seem like nothing happened on the HTML form, no error message is displayed if I pass the wrong input details, and if it is the right ones then the next or "Homepage" HTML code is not returned.

Why ? Do I need to activate the button also ? If so how do I do this here are the buttons details:

```
type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Login"
```

Thanks 
Ulrich

---

What it is returning is the following html code:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css"> 
.m0  {
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial;
color: black;
background-color: black;
font-size: x-small;;
  }
.m1  {
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial;
color: white;
background-color: red;
font-size: x-small;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
width: 100%;
border-top-style: double;
border-right-style: double;
border-bottom-style: double;
border-left-style: double;
  }
```

I didn't post everything but you get the idea.

---

Hi, Ok I found the answer what I needed to do was also define that the login button is pressed:

```
userid=G4737326&psword=UwwiTest&btnLogin=Login
```

Now I just need to figure out how to post the results that I am gettig back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Posting what you're seeing returned would be helpful.  Without more information, I can't tell you whats wrong with your code, but I can suggest trying [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).  From your question, you might find the Form Based Login [Example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) helpful.

EDIT:

It sounds like you're trying to simulate a button press.  If this is the case, you do NOT need to scrap the HTML from the page.  You need to figure out the URL the button press is generating, and submit that programmatically.  You then likely need to read the header, and determine what login cookie was set.  [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) already does this for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks I really want to do it with standard Java code, I know that it is possible.

Comment: Anything is possible, but in the realm of possibilities there are certain choices which are more effective than others. For example: using HTTPClient and thus dropping your limitation of not using an external API means you get many features which URLConnection does not provide out of the box. Features you really need.